# splitting values and assigning separate columns to each values in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string as follows :

```
2017-11-27T09:59:57.278-06:00,,"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]"
2017-11-27T10:00:17.250-06:00,,"[0.13055123127828835, -62.0, -76.0]"
```

I would like to have following in my data frame:

```
09:59:57.278  0.2094101093721778  -65.0  -76.0
10:00:17.250  0.13055123127828835 -62.0  -76.0
```

I tried to strip the first value as:

```
a = "2017-11-27T09:59:57.278-06:00,,\"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]\""
b = a.strip("2017-11-27T")
```

I got following output :
`9:59:57.278-06:00,,"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]"`

I actually wanted `09:59:57.278-06:00,,"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]"`

Comment: Duplicate of a question I asked today: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458706/expanding-pandas-string-column-of-floats-memory-efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Your `strip` removes *all combination* of the characters provided, so it also removed the preceding `0` from `09`.  You might want to do one of the following instead:

```
a = "2017-11-27T09:59:57.278-06:00,,\"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]\""
b = a.replace("2017-11-27T","")
```

**OR**

```
b = ''.join(a.split("2017-11-27T")[1:])
```

**Output (for both)**

> `'09:59:57.278-06:00,,"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]"'`

If you have different dates though (and hardcoding usually is a bad practice anyways), you probably want to convert that segment of the string as a `datetime` object and represent it again in the string:

```
t = a.split(",")    
t[0] = datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.strptime(t[0][0:-6], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"),"%H:%M:%S.%f")
b = ''.join(t)
```

The best way though if it's intended for your DataFrame, is probably just interpret the date with `pandas`.  See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650853/how-to-convert-string-with-timezone-to-datetime-in-utc-with-python) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
import pandas as pd

lin = '2017-11-27T09:59:57.278-06:00,,"[0.2094101093721778, -65.0, -76.0]"\n 2017-11-27T10:00:17.250-06:00,,"[0.13055123127828835, -62.0, -76.0]"'
chrToReplace = [',,','[',']','"',',']

y =[]
# Iterate through your lines
for x in lin.splitlines():
    for c in chrToReplace:
        if c in x:
            x = x.replace(c," ")
    x= x.split()
    n = 0
    z ={}
    for elm in x:
        z.update({"V"+str(n):elm})
        n += 1
    y.append(z)

df = pd.DataFrame(y)
print(df)
```

This gives you

```
                               V0                   V1     V2     V3
 0  2017-11-27T09:59:57.278-06:00   0.2094101093721778  -65.0  -76.0
 1  2017-11-27T10:00:17.250-06:00  0.13055123127828835  -62.0  -76.0
```